# Naming variables based on user input (Java)

Tags: java, variables

I can't seem to figure out how to proceed here. I am trying to make a family tree program that interprets user input and creates and draws new nodes in an animation window. For example, the user would type "John son of Jim", and a node labelled John would appear under an already present node labelled Jim.

The graphics aspect of this is already done, but I do not know how to proceed for adding children and linking them to the right parent. Do I create an arraylist for this?

```
String testString = wordTextField.getText();
String[] parts = testString.split(" ");
String firstWord = parts[0];
String lastWord = parts[parts.length - 1];
TreeNode *child's name* = new TreeNode(String firstWord, TreeNode *parent's name*);
```

In the code above, the last line is not correct, but I've labelled it like that to show the types they are in the TreeNode method. The asterisks are what I would like the variable names to be as String values, but I understand this may not be possible. What can I do to get this working? I want the user to be able to continuously create children nodes, and children nodes for those children nodes, with only one root parent. I want to be able to organize which parent has which children, and assign correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that and neither should you. What you need is to link parents to children. It's hard to propose something concrete as I don't know the context of your application. You seem to be on the right track, seeing as you pass the parent node in the constructor of the child. Why do you need the variables to be named after user input here? Variable names can be anything.

Comment: I guess I don't need them to be linked to user input. But if the user for example makes John the son of Michael, and Michael the son of Sam. Then the user makes Sam have another son. How do I go about keeping track of which parent is which? If the user is giving names to the parents dynamically, how do I direct a new TreeNode method to a TreeNode variable for the parent?

Comment: You need to use proper Object Oriented Programming. Create a proper family model in which one node can have two parents and an indefinite number of children. Each node should have a "name" variable which can be changed freely without breaking anything. Nodes should also have properties like birth and death dates, etc. Then it is just the case of properly linking the objects together and parsing the structure to display it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was able to link the parent to his/her child by keeping all names in the order entered in an arraylist, then assigning the current child to the appropriate index of said arraylist using a for loop. I don't know if that makes any sense, but it seems to have done the job.

Comment: At this stage whatever works is good, I guess, but I still strongly suggest you take some OOP tutorials (Object Oriented Programming) as it's a core skill.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that but if you want one string respresents for one node, you can use Map. Firstly, init the map for holding all nodes:

```
Map<String, TreeNode> nodes = new HashMap<String, TreeNode>();
```

The constructor of TreeNode will become:

```
TreeNode(String firstWord, String parent){
    TreeNode parent = nodes.get(parent);
    //...
}
```

Whenever create a node, put it in the map:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(firstWord, "parent's name");
nodes.put("child's name", node);
```